# C# Windows Service with Registry Access and rundll32.exe

Tags: c#, registry

I have a C# Windows Service running under the LocalSystem account.
I need access to the Windows registry in this service. I assume that this is only possible when running as LocalSystem? Or can I install the service as User context and have access to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`?

The systems where the service is used is normally just used by one user. So there will be just "one" `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. Another option is, to setup Remote Apps not for one user, but for all users. But I have no idea how to do that. Currently I know only the way listed below by running rundll32.exe.

As a second requirement I need to execute rundll32.exe to create RemoteApp Connection.
The following Code is not working properly:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "/C rundll32.exe tsworkspace,WorkspaceSilentSetup C:\\RemoteConfig.wcx";

using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

What must the Service be like to access `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`?
How can I run rundll32.exe? just running it directly caused some trouble when testing it in a console application. But with help of cmd.exe it worked.

Comment: You could create a specific user for your service and grant registry access and enough privileges to start RunDLL (which I think requires admin access). Then you'd configure the service to run as that user (password management at deployment time complicates things)  You might also consider a _Service Account_ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn617203(v=ws.11) ) or a _Group Managed Service Account_.  Why run `RunDLL32` via `cmd` and not just as an exe?

Comment: Oh, I just notices your last sentence.  What do you think HKEY_CURRENT_USER references if there is no one logged in (or if more than one person is logged in)?

Comment: What do you mean by "the registry in this service"? The Windows registry is a system-wide service...

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question above. Hope that is better now.

Comment: The service basically can't access HKEY_CURRENT_USER for another user - so you must access HKEY_USERS and find the hive you want. Hives are named by SID, so you could get the local user's SID and pass it to the service as the USER to work for? The hive will only exist when the user is logged in. Not sure why this would need to be a service...

Comment: Thanks NetMage! That hint was very helpful. Now my only problem is how to execute rundll32 from the service.